# Собрать все файлы в один

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Есть задача - на сервере собирать все js и css файлы в один. Мне в голову пришло получать содержимое файлов через file_get_contents и записывать в один, удаляя пробелы и табы через preg_replace. Насколько это хорошая идея?

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовая библиотека, https://code.google.com/p/minify/. Но если будете делать сами, то не забудьте про кеширование. Не так часто эти файлы меняются